# How to Save sensor_msgs/Image

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got Gazebo 2.2.3 and ROS Indigo set up, and I have a plugin that allows a stereo camera to publish images from Gazebo to ROS. I've run rosbag with the image topics, and it has no problems recording or playing them. The issue now is that I need to somehow either save the images themselves or have access to the pointers for the camera images. Can someone give me some pointers on how to do so, preferably via C++ code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194067/how-to-save-sensor_msgs/image/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/18898/k.-zeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you use [cv_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge) you can then use all of OpenCV which includes operating on and saving images.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on 2014-10-05**:
imwrite as explained [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html) would do the job, in C++, since ROS supports OpenCV.